# Freeze Cloud Services for no billing

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-billing-api

We have few cloud services with both VMs and web worker roles in it. Is there a way to "freeze" or stop them to not be billed but if we want to start them again?

I saw some answers but most of them are outdated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to "freeze" or stop them to not be billed but if we
>   want to start them again?

Unfortunately no. You must delete the cloud service deployment to stop the billing. Stopped cloud service will continue to incur charges.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav Mantri. What do you mean under "delete deployment"?
Thanks

Comment: By delete deployment I mean deleting deleting the worker role from your cloud service. You should be able to do so through the portal (delete staging/production deployment). You don't have to delete cloud service. An empty cloud service does not incur any charges.

Comment: Thanks again.
So can we conclude that there is no way to save this environment to not be billed and to start it whenever we want? (Like VMs works)

And one more question - What about if we stop the separate VMs (in the cloud service? Is the bill changed?

Comment: @KrassiMarinov - please don't ask additional questions in comments. if you have a specific new question, please ask as such. Gaurav already answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

One detail not covered in @gaurav's answer: with Cloud Services, you can scale your number of web or worker instances down to 1, minimizing cost. If you won't be using them for an extended period of time, you can also choose to scale down to a smaller instance size.

Virtual Machines may be stopped (where they're no longer billed, aside from the storage costs related to OS + data disks).